# Jquery UI Range Slider Not Updating the Knockout binding

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, custom-binding

I have a knockout observable array containing data of a person's past medical problems.
I created a Jquery Range Slider whose minimum range is his Birth year while max range is Current Year. When  User slides through the slider, the only those medical problems should be viewed which fall in the range.

So far I have accomplished to view the medical problems if the range is saved in the div,
But I am unable to make it work with the slider.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bX9pP/

That's the viewmodel code:

```
var viewModel = {
    one : ko.observableArray([
    {
        HistoryIcon: "img/Surgeon.png",
        HistoryItem: "Laparoscopic Cholecystectomy",
        HistoryItemVenue: "Dr.Rao Khan KRL Hospital",
        Date: "16th May 2013",
        Year: "2013",
        Tag: "None"
    },
    {
        HistoryIcon: "img/haayeoye",
        HistoryItem: "Laparoscopic Cholecystectomy",
        HistoryItemVenue: "Dr.Rao Khan KRL Hospital",
        Date: "16th May 2011",
        Year: "2011",
        Tag: "None"
    },
    {
        HistoryIcon: "img/amedical_pot_pills.png",
        HistoryItem: "Symbicort, 50mgs(PainRelief)",
        HistoryItemVenue: "Prescribed by Dr.Jay Rajpoot Shifa Intl Hospital",
        Date: "16th May 2012",
        Year: "2012",
        Tag: "None"},
    {
        HistoryIcon: "img/amedical_pot_pills.png",
        HistoryItem: "Symbicort, 50mgs(PainRelief)",
        HistoryItemVenue: "Prescribed by Dr.Jay Rajpoot Shifa Intl Hospital",
        Date: "16th May 2015",
        Year: "2015",
        Tag: "None"}
    ])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

That's the script to get div elements' innerHTML:

```
var temp=document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML;
var temp1=document.getElementById("s2").innerHTML;
```

The Slider Script Code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({ // Slider Jq ui 
      range: true, //Range Slider
      min: 1960, //Minimum Value
      max: 2013, //Maximum Value
      step: 1, //Steps
      values: [ 1960, 2013 ], //Initial Value

        change: function( event, ui ) { //When slides
          //    $( "#s1" ).html( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);// Values append to div, [0] being min , [1] being max
          //    $( "#s2" ).html( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);// Values append to div, [0] being min , [1] being max
          $( "#s1" ).html( ui.values[ 1 ]);
          $( "#s2" ).html( ui.values[ 0 ]);   
        }
    }); 
});
```

Finally, the HTML code

```
<div id="s1">2012</div>
<div id="s2">2013</div>

<div  id="slider-range"></div>

<div data-bind="foreach: one">
    <!-- ko if: Year <= temp1 && Year >= temp   -->
    <div class="span4" data-bind="text: Date" ></div>
    <div class="span4" data-bind="text: HistoryIcon" ></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for *range slider*. And for displaying the item under the range you can create a [computed obervable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), which will recompute every time whenever your Min or Max date observable changes.

*custom binding for range slider (javascript)*:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.rangeSlider = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor)
    {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        var params =  allBindingsAccessor() || {};
        options.change = function(e, ui)
        {
            params.MinValue(ui.values[0]);
            params.MaxValue(ui.values[1]);
        }
        options.slide = function(e, ui)
        {
            params.MinValue(ui.values[0]);
            params.MaxValue(ui.values[1]);
        }            
        $(element).slider(options);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
          $(element).slider("destroy");
        });
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="rangeSlider: {range: true, min:500, max:15000 , step:100}, minValue: chosenMinPrice, maxValue: chosenMaxPrice"></div>
```

I have created a fiddle check this:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bX9pP/12/)

Let me know is this what you are trying to achieve ?